# Why are so many old questions churning up on the front page?

Tags: support

I see that someone named Tim Post has been editing quite a few questions on the site, churning a lot of things onto the front page. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tim is a community manager for Stack Exchange, and is working on organizing some of the [site tags](https://sound.stackexchange.com/tags) in order to:

- Make sure questions that have tags used only once are tagged with appropriate and more frequently used tags, as single use tags are automatically culled by the system every month
- Create tag synonyms {plural} -> {singular} / {typo} -> {actual-tag} so that related questions can be found using the single tag
- Remove certain [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) where appropriate, with great discretion

When tag edits are made, the system automatically places the question on the front page for a short period of time. The tag maintenance will continue in several hour sessions over the next few days.

If you spot the opportunity for a synonym, or a tag that really doesn't describe a question and think it is a good candidate for removal, please feel free to post it as an answer here!